# Keep only new faces from Blender Solidify modifier

Tags: mesh

I am using the Solidify modifier from Blender. I just want to have the new surface that the modifier gave me. I dont see an option that its possible.

Is there a way how to do this?

Thank you

Simon

Comment: HI there :).Please add some images to visualize your problem.Thank u

Comment: you can disable the Fill Rim option, but of course you'll still have the original surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Via a script**

Select the object with the solidify modifier (and only a solidify modifier) and run script. Creates a new object with only the faces created by the solidify modifier.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

ob = context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(ob, dg)
bmesh.ops.delete(
        bm,
        geom=bm.faces[0:len(ob.data.polygons)],
        context='FACES'
        )
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Solidify")

bm.to_mesh(me)
ob2 = bpy.data.objects.new("Solidify", me)
context.collection.objects.link(ob2)

ob2.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you said i have a feeling that you didn't apply the modifier

[image]

NOTE that you can't apply the modifier if you are in edit mode or the object is linked with another object